# How to add React (third party libraries and css together) to html website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I read lot of stuff how to add react component to html website but it is only simple js component without any import(other component or css). please don't repeat me this.( There is on reactjs.org and same lot of other webiste).

I think maybe need webpack but it is very difficult to me. So please help me (us) with step by step how to implement this an concrete example.

Comment: Go get a course on Udemy for $12 that'll teach you how to build a full stack web app using React. Tons of tutorials on YouTube as well. Sounds like you haven't done your homework and you want someone else to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you. I yet did more react course. But these not solve my problem. I search yet youtube lot of and i  enroll more react cousre on udemy.  I am webdeveloper it's not my housework. I deploy my projects first VPS  and do the backend with node express. Now I deploy to firebase and if I place the html website template  to the public map and I use create-react-app then not recognized several js file in the template and the firebase script also.( firebase is not a function). But If I leave create-react-app it's work fine. I try lot of and I don't know the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

A great place for getting started with a react application is by using `create-react-app`.

This will help you get a project set up in minutes and will sort babel / pre-compilation for you. It offers a modern build setup with no configuration and you will be able to add additional packages to this project using npm or yarn.

You can find instructions here:

[Getting Started](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Note: Make sure you have node.js installed on your machine

Comment: Thank you your answer but I did yet hundreds of create-react-app projects. I can't integrate this with the exsisting html, css javascript project. React not have got proffesional design template or only very poor. But html website template have more thousends. So I can't thinking the design and write tons of html and css. I write severeal React component yet and I wolid like integrate together, I try with the reactjs.org solution but it concern only one component that is an js file.(babel automatic version method  for production it's work fine).